# Parent div not resizing correctly to fit the dynamically generated grid

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a gallery style web page that will display thumbnails of recently added videos to my NAS server.

I am dynamically inserting images(image path) and text(title) from MySQL into a 3 wide grid and my parent div is not resizing correctly, my grid items are going off the bottom of the parent div.

**html code**

```
    include_once 'database.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0">
        <title>New Movies</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='logo'>
            <img id='logo-img' src="images/Logo_Banner.png" alt="OOPS"> 
        </div>

        <div id="header">
            <h1 id="header-text">MOST RECENT</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="gallery-container">
            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT title,path FROM Website.images;";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    
                if ($resultCheck > 0){
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        echo 
                        "<div class='container'>
                            <img class='covers' src={$row['path']} alt='OOPS'>
                            <h2>{$row['title']}</h2>
                        </div>";
    
                    }
                }   
            ?>
        </div>
    
    </body>

    <a hidden href="https://www.freepik.com/vectors/background">Background vector created by pikisuperstar - www.freepik.com</a>

</html>
```

**css code**

```
.container{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 5%;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: lightgray;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        word-break: break-all;
}

.gallery-container{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    padding: 5%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 5%;
    justify-items: center;
    background-color: gray;
}

#header{
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    margin: 0% 10%;
        text-align: center;
    color: black;
        background-color: white;
    font-size: xxx-large;
    font-style: italic;
}

.covers{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#logo-img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0% auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#logo{
    margin: 0% 5%;
    width:auto;
    height: auto;
}

body{
    background-image: url("images/Background.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many more hours of tinkering/troubleshooting I finally managed to figure it out. It seems that my problem was the *grid gap* option so I swap grid gap for margins and that seems to have solved the problem.
Hope this saves someone time in the future